# yii2: set another site for link with Html::a

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-extension

i have a link (href) to another site but i have problem

this is my code :

```
          return Html::a('Create More', ["https://face.com/"], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'role' => 'modal-remote']);
```

why my link is a new action?
i want change my baseurl to https://face.com/ but dosnt work

this is my new link:

```
https://niniplus.com/newadmin/index.php/https://face.com
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By just removing the array `["https://face.com/"]`, an absolute url will be return.

```
return Html::a('Create More', "https://face.com/", ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'role' => 'modal-remote']);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an absolute url you can call yii\helpers\Url::to() yourself, before passing the URL to this method, like this:

```
return Html::a('Create More', Url::to('https://face.com/', true), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'role' => 'modal-remote']);
```

Comment: Will need to import class like this: use yii\helpers\Url;

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `use yii\helpers\Url;` into view and you should write your anchor tag like below:

```
return Html::a('Create More',  Url::to('https://face.com/', true), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'role' => 'modal-remote']);
```